# Question about a definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Definition of limit:

> Let the function $f$ be defined on a punctured neighbourhood $N$ of a point $c$. Then $f(x)$ tends to the limit $l$ as $x$ tends to $c$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon \text{ granted } 0< |x - c| < \delta$.

Definition of continuity:

> A function $f$ defined on an interval $I$ that contains $c$ as an interior point is continuous at $c$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon \text{ granted } |x - c| < \delta$.

Why must $c$ in the definition of continuity be interior? Let $I = [c, d]$. Then $c$ is not interior, but can't we still define a one-sided continuity? Does $c$ have to be interior so that we can consider $x$ from both sides of $c$? But then in the definition of functional limit above, $c$ is a limit point and so if $N = (c, d)$, we can only define a one-sided limit, correct? So why this limitation in the definition of continuity above?

Is there a better reason or are these definitions an author's personal choice? Thanks.

Comment: Those are definitely not the definitions. YOu're mixing up the implications

Comment: @peek-a-boo, fixed it.

Comment: The reason for "interior point" is just to streamline the definition without making additional comments (not a good reason). It is easy to modify to take into account the end points as well. You just have to understand what a neighborhood of the endpoint looks like. So you can say "$f:I\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous at $c\in I$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap I$, we have $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$". (For an interior point, one can always choose $\delta$ small enough so that $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\subset I$, so intersecting is superfluous).

Comment: @peek-a-boo, I see. So the given defn of the functional limit above is more general whereas the given defn of the continuity above artificially and weirdly(?) ignores the endpoints. Thanks.